# can't navigate first uri segment (controller) in wamp

Tags: codeigniter, wamp

When i navigate to my main page in on localhost (127.0.0.1/myproject) I have no problems. It displays the page as it should.

However, it asks to login, and when I click the link, it brings me straight back to the WAMP details page.  It navigates to (127.0.0.1/myproject/tank/auth/)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I use XAMP, but I think the environments are similar.  The trick is to get the base url right.

What is your base url set to in config.php?

Mine look something like:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/myWWWdirectory/MySpecificProject/";
```

where my CI files are in the 'MySpecificProject' folder.

On my machine, `myWWWdirectory/MySpecificProject` is in my `htdocs` folder.

Comment: just tried this, but no luck unfortunately.  I have looked into virtual hosts and editing the windows / host file. Is this necessary?

Comment: I don't use virtual hosts on my local machine.  I just serve files off sub-folders in my htdocs directory.  This leads to rather long URL's in development but it works ok.